# How to increase the number of faces in a model

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am an absolute beginner with Blender, and to 3D modeling in general.

I am taking a tutorial and my extruded plane with a skin modifier applied is comprised of basically 11 quads, the tutorial I am watching has 32 quads (if I am correct in assuming that each "side" is a quad).

Is it possible to increase and decrease the number of quads that an extruded plane with a skin modifier would have?

Comment: Quads are the faces (ones with four sides) If you would like to quickly increase the number of quads, add a sub surf modifier.

Comment: Another way to increase the number of faces is to select one or more faces, and use the subdivide tool (in edit mode, W > subdivide). If desirable, you can increase the number of divisions in attribute panel (displaying at the bottom of the tool shelf, or separately by pressing the F6 key. This adds immediate geometry to the mesh, without having to wait for the geometry to be applied, as is the case with the subdivisison surface modifier.

Comment: The part about **"extruded plane with a skin modifier"** don't seem relevant.

Comment: tysm! my cube started at 0 poly for some reason

Answer (score 9):

It's hard to know how to help without many details. If you're following a modelling tutorial and you're supposed to have 32 faces and you only have 11, you may want to go back and double check you followed the tutorial properly.

But your question was how to increase the number of faces, and here's a few ways how...

## Method 1: Using Subdivide Tool

Select your object and make sure you are in edit mode.

[image]

Click this button to enter face select mode:

[image]

Select the faces that you wish to divide by right clicking on them:

[image]

Press <kbd>W</kbd>, and when this menu pops up, click `Subdivide`:

[image]

You can repeat this as many times as you want. Each time the selected faces will be divided into 4 new faces if they are quads.

[image]

## Method 2: Using Knife Tool

Again, select your object and make sure you're in edit mode:

[image]

Press <kbd>K</kbd> to activate the knife tool. Now you can draw lines where you want to cut your object:

[image]

And press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you are satisfied, or <kbd>ESC</kbd> to cancel.

## Method 3: Ring Cut Tool

This is essentially a much more controlled, but limited, version of the knife tool. Once again make sure you select your object and are in edit mode. Press <kbd>CTRL + R</kbd> to activate the ring cut tool, and mouse over an edge. The purple line is where the cut will be made.

[image]

You can scroll up and down with your mouse to increase/decrease the number of cuts, and click to perform the cut.

At this point you can adjust the position of the cuts, or right click to keep them in the center.

## Method 4: Subdivision Surface Modifier

This one is a little different. This time, make sure you are in **object mode**:

[image]

With your object select, go to the modifiers panel on the right (it looks like a wrench) and click `Add Modifier` and select `Subdivision Surface`.

[image]

You can adjust the number of cuts with the numbers where it says "View" and "Render". If you don't want your object to be rounded, click on `Simple`. Click `Apply` when you are satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

As it has already been said, apply the Subdivision surface modifier right after the skin modifier to control the number of faces you get. There is no way to do such directly in skin modifier

Useful reading and tutorial:
[Understanding the Power of the Skin Modifier in Blender](http://blog.digitaltutors.com/understanding-power-skin-modifier-blender/)

Comment: You need to explain how to add the modifier, for someone who might not know how.